# Android Layout for Simple Game with new updates

Tags: android, layout

I understand this question is asked in past, but most of the questions I can find are very old. So, wanted to request suggestions from the experts.

I am trying to create a simple car game, where the car is going to be placed at the center of the layout and then some of the other cars which would be dynamically changing their positions would be placed relative to the central car. Based on this definitely i need to change the position of different objects through the android code.

I understand that most people use relative layout, as it is very flexible. But is it the right choice ? Does the constraint layout show better possibility ? I would not be having any buttons on the screen for the game manipulation, it would be done through another hardware input.

My question is which layout is better for this type of functionalities and what is the best way to update the position of different objects through code ? I ask this because the objects would be changed every 100ms with a different position.